# Confused between potential energies

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, conventions

Let us suppose an object of mass $m$ has been raised $h$ meter above. From definition of gravitational potential energy, the potential energy of the ball should be $-\frac{GMm}{R+h}$. But now let us do that in another process. That is via intgeration which yiels $\int_{R}^{R+h} Fdr=\int_{R}^{R+h}\frac{GMm}{r^2}dr$ which gives the answer $GMm(\frac{1}{R}-\frac{1}{R+h})$ which is basically the change of gravitational potential energy of the system? Then what is the actual answer?
I am asking this because while solving problems when asked about total energy of a satellite,i saw many books using potential energy as $-\frac{GMm}{R}$ while some others use $GMm(\frac{1}{R}-\frac{1}{R+h})$ which is a huge dilemma at hand.

Comment: You always deal with relative potential energies, never absolute values. The first formula gives you the difference in potential energy with respect to the center of the earth, while the second gives you the difference in potential energy with respect to the surface of the earth. You cannot measure potential energy, but you can measure the difference in potential energy between two points.

Comment: How is the first the difference in potential energy with respect to center of earth? Because the earth and the body are $R+h$ units away. The gravitational potential energy of this system is defined by $-\frac{GMm}{r}$ where the reference level is $\infty$ and not center of earth.

Comment: You're right, @RenatoRenatoRenato was careless; the potential energy for the first formula is taken with respect to $\infty$. Even then, the second formula is indeed taken with respect to the surface of the Earth, and so should not be the same.

Comment: Yes, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculus is right. What you've computed is the *change* in potential energy over a displacement $h$, not the total potential energy.

**Gravitational potential energy is negative.**

An object's potential energy is opposite the amount of energy it would take to move it from where it is to infinity. For a negative-valued force like gravity, closer to the bottom means it would take more positive energy to lift it to infinity, hence the smaller potential energy is a *larger negative number*.

An object's *change* in potential energy is opposite the amount of work done by the field over the distance. It is positive if the work done is negative (positive increase in height times negative force), and negative if the work done is positive (negative change in height times negative force).

Note $\frac{1}{R}-\frac{1}{R+\Delta r} = \frac{R+\Delta r}{R(R+\Delta r)}-\frac{R}{R(R+\Delta r)} = \frac{\Delta r}{R(R+\Delta r)} \approx \frac {\Delta r}{R^2}$ for $\Delta r \ll R$

and

$-\frac{GM}{R^2} = g = -9.81m/s^2$ for earth mass $M$, earth radius $R$

hence

$\Delta U \approx -mg\Delta r$ for $\Delta r \ll R$

Which you'll recognize, although the cabal of evil psychopaths that write high-school curricula probably made you learn it as "$PE = mgh$" (with positive $g$) in order to confuse you.